# Is there an online resource for finding microcontroller with specific requirements?

Tags: microcontroller

When looking at digikey with the advanced search chrome extension ([Link](https://www.eewiki.net/display/Motley/advancedsearch+Greasemonkey+Userscript+for+Digikey.com)) on I noticed that some features of the microcontrollers are not recorded (such as MIPI, PCIe, UBC, etc).

Is there a website that does record every (or most) microcontroller features?

Comment: You will probably need to use the parametric search for microcontroller families offered by the manufacturer (if they offer one). For example, Atmel has a parametric search: click "Microcontroller Selector" from their [products page](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/default.aspx?src=parent).

Comment: For PIC there is the [Microchip Advanced Part Selector](http://www.microchip.com/maps/microcontroller.aspx)

Comment: I have looked around for such a site, however the data is usually patchy and incomplete. Manufacturers usually have good parametric search, for example ST have product selectors at the level of individual families, e.g. [STM32 Families](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169) and [TI ARM](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/arm/products.page) where you'll need to select a family.

Comment: Your best bet is probably finding a manufacturer that seems to have what you need by doing a supplier search such as digi-key and then going to their own website and doing their parametric search.

Comment: Which microcontroller does have PCIe?

Comment: You'd probably have to go to a SoC for PCIe.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, like Intal Quark X1000