# Non-manufacturer microcontroller selection site?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, avr

I'm  looking for a site which I can input my desired micro-controller characteristics. I have found the manufacturer websites...but those will only show their micro-controllers.

I.E. there's a site for PICS and a site for AVR, etc. but I'm  looking for one that will select possibilities from ALL manufacturers, other than that it's  just running around in the dark...

Comment: +1 good question. A site like that would be very helpful, but I don't think it exists. You could try the sites of distributors such as Digikey, Farnell, TME, go to the microntroller section and use their parametric filters..

Comment: [Duplicate question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/126865/52562) - although that one has no answer, it may have useful comments.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. Did a search, but didn't  see it. Will remove at moderator request, but had a useful answer.

Comment: Digikey superb. www.digikey.com. Also eg http://www.findchips.com/,  http://www.eciaauthorized.com/ , https://www.verical.com/ ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Digi-Key has a [broad search tool](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/embedded-microcontrollers/2556109?k=microcontroller) where you can select parts across 30 microcontroller manufacturers. It has ARMs, AVRs, PICs, 8051 derivatives etc. -- over 48,500 individual parts.

[(Click for a larger view)

[image: Digi-Key search tool]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQI64.jpg)

You can search for core size (8, 16, 32), speed, peripherals, program size, RAM size, EEPROM size, # of I/O pins, and package across all parts.

Answer (score 11):

[parts.io](http://parts.io/)

It is still in the alpha test stage, but it is becoming useful. It is not a retailer or manufacturer or distributor, so there isn't any agenda.

Comment: [Octopart](https://octopart.com/) is similar, but more mature

Answer (score 3):

I usually use these distributors to find my MCU:

- [DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com/)
- [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Integrated-Circuits-ICs/Embedded-Processors-Controllers/_/N-a86bc/)
- [Farnell](http://www.farnell.com)
- [Arrow](http://parts.arrow.com/product/Microcontroller)
- [TME](http://www.tme.eu/en/katalog/#id_category=100590&s_field=artykul&s_order=ASC&page=1)

Comment: I could do that, but it would be incredibly useful to have a website which deduced which manufacturer fit the bill. I'm  a professional web developer. Perhaps I'll  get a team together.

Comment: @Allenph The vendors that I mentioned above are the best and the biggest on the world(especially Mouser and DigiKey). approximately you can find any MCU that could be available for an embedded engineer. they are good sources. Why shouldn't you use them?

Comment: Well, it would be nice to have a website that would compare all of the manufacturers at once. That way you could get the lowest price, and specific variations in characteristics in one place without having to do multiple searches then compare the best candidates manually.

Comment: @Allenph No need to do multiple searches. even one of them is enough. there is no such a magic website. for example try to find this MCU P8X32A in the parts.io! while you can see it in Mouser: http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Parallax/P8X32A-D40/?qs=QGk6feVlqMKUIA06dhUaew%3D%3D

Comment: @Allenph The list in this answer is actually of distributors (not vendors), and each of them sells parts from just about every vendor. Like Roh said, you only need to search one of these sites for your search to be comprehensive.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. Thanks for clearing that up. That makes things quite a bit simpler.